# Placeholder settings on sub-renderings

Tags: placeholders, presentation

This is something that's been bugging me and I was curious to others' solutions. Let's say you have a template that you've done standard values on for the presentation...you pick a layout, put renderings on, put placeholder settings on. Let's say one of these renderings is a sub-layout (in the traditional sense of the word, not an web forms rendering) with placeholders on it.

Is there a way to specify the placeholder settings for the sub-layout such that they always stay with the sub-layout? I hate the idea of having to specify all of these placeholder settings on a page template that may or may not use the sub-layout, and I'd hate to always have to specify a template for the sub-layout if all it is is a layout detail (like multiple columns to subdivide a page) and doesn't need a template for data reasons.

Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to pinning a component on a page? Like "news article will always have a embedded content component, which can't be removed"?

Comment: No, more like I have a sub-layout called Three Columns, with three placeholders (left, right, middle). I want placeholder settings for those three columns, but I want them to be associated with/follow the sub-layout. Right now I'm anticipating them by putting the placeholder settings on the page template level, which is overkill for the page template. But I'm trying to avoid needed a template just to support the sub-layout if that makes sense.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it. What about a baked-in template that has the placeholder settings, that I connect up to the sub-layout rendering in the rendering definition itself? Since there's no other data template, in the case I'm thinking of, that will ever be connected, that should work, no? (if folks agree I'll post it as the answer.)

Comment: Can you create placeholder settings items for left, right, and middle under `/sitecore/layout/Placeholder Settings` and define your allowed controls there? This does not require anything to be done on the template or component levels.

Comment: I could, Derek, but then I'm creating three placeholder settings when one might do. If we consider this as a three-column layout (each column is col-md-4), then each placeholder might take a "Single Column" placeholder setting. I think I see what you're saying, but I'd want to reuse the placeholder setting.

Comment: You don't need 3 placeholder settings. Create one placeholder settings item but do not set the placeholder key. Then assign this same placeholder settings items and the keys for each ph in presentation details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the most common extension is to use the rules engine.  You create a processor for the `GetPlaceholderRenderings` pipeline that uses the rules engine to add/remove renderings.  Here are some links to various implementations of the idea.  I'm sure there are more out there too.

- https://github.com/matthewkenny/ConditionalPlaceholderSettings
- https://github.com/williamsk/SitecorePlaceholderSettingsRules
- http://shanebair.me/2015/09/27/smart-placeholder-settings-how-it-works/
- https://brainjocks.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SDD/Placeholder+Settings+Rules

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question, but I'd like to see opinions on whether folks think this might be the answer.

So in this scenario, the rendering that is my sub-layout has no actual data going to it; it's purely a placeholder deal. Think a main layout that has a Bootstrap col-md-12, and I want a sub-layout that has three col-md-4's, with a placeholder in each. So I create the rendering in Sitecore, connect to a CSHTML file with the markup, and in theory I'm done except for "where do I put the placeholder settings?"

So on the layout page connected to the template, we have this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("main")
</div>
```

The placeholder settings for "main" can be assigned as the default key on the placeholder setting itself, as discussed below. Then we have a rendering that consists of the following, with no template required because it's just placeholders:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("main-left")
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("main-center")
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("main-right")
</div>
```

Each of these placeholders would use the same placeholder setting, let's call it "Single Column". So the question is, where do I assign "Single Column" to affect these three placeholders? With the caveat that this rendering may not be used, and I'd prefer not to junk up my page template with placeholder settings that may never be used.

I can't put them on the rendering, that doesn't work correctly. So after spelling the case out above, the thought that came to me is to create a template with no fields, and all it has on it are placeholder settings. I then attach that template to my rendering in the "Data Source" field, so they're always connected.

In theory this would work. The one thought that occurs to me as I write this, in the standard values of the template to specify the presentation details, can you specify just the placeholder settings, or does it force you to pick a layout and perhaps a rendering as well? If so, could you create a completely blank layout (I mean a CSHTML file that's totally empty, no markup at all) and then pick some dummy rendering that's connected to an unused placeholder key (so it could never render on the page) just to trick the system?

It sounds like a long way around to achieve the effect, but the ultimate goal is, for these renderings that are nothing more than sub-layouts that contain placeholders, to keep the placeholder settings with the sub-layout, and not "junk up" the page template with placeholder settings/keys it might never use.

Comment: I'm confused about what you need to do Ken. You do not assign placeholder settings to specific rendering.

Comment: And maybe this is where I'm over engineering, but I'm trying to get things handled better. On my page template, I have a single placeholder that spans the whole page, easy enough to assign a placeholder setting to the template and hook it to the key.

Now I create a rendering that's intended as a sub layout...it has three columns with three placeholders, each with their own key. I have a single placeholder setting called "Single Column" that I can assign to each of these three columns.

Where best to assign the placeholder settings for my sub layout? Page template?

Comment: I'd create the placeholder setting item and set components allowed there, and leave the key empty. Then on the standard values of the pages where this will be used, add a placeholder rendering pointing to the newly created and set the placeholder name (do this for each of the columns) see: 
https://varunvns.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/placeholder-settings-empower-your-page-editor-users-part-2/
Might be confusing at the beginning but once you do it couple of times you'll master it.

Comment: That did help me understand and trim down the number of placeholder settings I had to apply to templates directly. I'm still having some confusion/issue with the specific case I'm thinking of, so I'll see if I can follow up later when I have time with some screenshots of what I'm doing to facilitate discussion. Thanks for the pointers so far. :)

Comment: josedbaez - I added some code samples above to try and better describe where I'm going with it. Does that still jive with where you're going? Thanks.

Comment: I believe so yeah. The only caveat is you say you "don't want to junk up with placeholder settings" which might be what my solution requires. Basically, what I'm suggesting is to create a placeholder settings item for "main" that allows you to drop your 3 column rendering. Then you create a placeholder settings (e.g. components) item for renderings allowed in these columns but leave "Placeholder key" empty.  Finally, on your template (base page?) presentation details you add the placeholder settings component and set the placeholder key here (will need to add for each column)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of and what I was trying to think of a way around. I wish you could set placeholder settings on a rendering to link them up to the point of origin, but it's not how Sitecore runs. I might try another idea I've been percolating and see if that works...if so I'll update and maybe blog it out too. Good discussion. :)

Comment: whats your concern about having them on the template though? XML gets too big?

Comment: I think it's a neatness thing...I feel like I'm putting placeholder settings on a template that don't need to be there all the time. I've tried the other tricks I was thinking of but they don't work, so I think this is the best way to go. I'm using dynamic placeholders which helps keep the bloat down.